# Command line script to delete Oracle records based on a column value

Tags: sql, oracle, cmd

I am completely new to scripting techniques.

My requirement is

1. To connect oracle through DOS script
2. Based on a column value need to delete the particular record

eg:

```
emp   sal    pt_dt
a     23     22-02-11
b     34     20-01-10
c     45     23-09-85
d     56     30-3-11
```

Based on the 30-3-11(`pt_dt` column), I need to delete the record d.

OS - Windows XP
DB - Oracle 10g

Answer (score 3):

Simplest method is to first write your sql (e.g. deleterec.sql) script, then call it from a batch (e.g. deleterec.bat) script.

Example contents of deleterec.sql:

```
DELETE emp WHERE pt_dt = TO_DATE('30-03-2011','DD-MM-RRRR');
```

Example contents of deleterec.bat:

```
sqlplus.exe scott/tiger@orcl @deleterec.sql
```

(replace scott/tiger@orcl with your user name, password and database instance)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a .bat like this:

```
@echo off
if %%1X==X goto noparam
echo DELETE FROM emp e WHERE e.emp = '%%1' > deleterec.sql
sqlplus.exe scott/tiger@orcl @deleterec.sql
delete deleterec.sql
goto end
:noparam
echo Usage: %%0 {employee id}
goto end
:end
echo Bye!
```

I admit I stole the sqlplus call from Jeffrey's answer. :-o

Comment: Forgot to mention this is quite risky. Any attempt to do this in batch is. In this particular case, when someone enters the employee id `'; drop database; --`, you'll be in trouble. If you are smart and remove the rights to drop the database, they can still write `' OR e.emp IS NOT NULL OR e.emp IS NULL`....